# Need help condensing javascript code that writes an object property value to the document based on user input.

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, object

this seems like it is a very basic question that i can't just can't seem to search properly so i'm going to keep it brief unless someone request otherwise.  I have the following javascript function that works,

```
zipCode.onchange = function () {
var zipPrice = document.getElementById('tripCost');
var zipCity = document.getElementById('cityState')

if ('z'+zipCode.value === 'z39429') { 
    zipPrice.textContent = price$$$$[7].z39429;
    zipCity.textContent = price$$$$[8].z39429;
} else if ('z'+zipCode.value === 'z39483'){
    zipPrice.textContent = price$$$$[7].z39483;
    zipCity.textContent = price$$$$[8].z39483;
}
```

in which it fills out the city and state info on the form as well as lists a price for the customer to gauge the cost.  the two relevant objects in the array contain well over a dozen zip codes however, and i feel like there aught to be a simpler way to do this in which i compare the user input directly to the property rather than manually keying in each input required.

one other note, i put the 'z' with the zip code number because i wasn't sure if my property names could start with a number.  if thats no the case the ill change the property names and remove the 'z+' from the function.

Comment: See the dupetarget for details, but: `var key = 'z'+zipCode.value; zipPrice.textContent = price$$$$[7][key]; zipCity.textContent = price$$$$[8][key];` You might want to check if you get `undefined` for either of those, which would mean it's a zip that isn't on the object.

Comment: *"i wasn't sure if my property names could start with a number"* They can, it's perfectly valid for a property name to start with a number: `var obj = {123: "one two three"};` (but don't do that for zipcodes, keep reading). Note that property names are always strings (or Symbols), so that's really `var obj = {"123": "one two three"};`, which is also valid (and essential for zipcodes, since they can start with 0).

Answer (score 0):

That code can be refactorized to (removing the 'z'):

```
zipCode.onchange = function () {
  var zipPrice = document.getElementById('tripCost');
  var zipCity = document.getElementById('cityState');

  zipPrice.textContent = price$$$$[7][zipCode.value];
  zipCity.textContent = price$$$$[8][zipCode.value];
}
```

Comment: Why?, you can create an object with numbers as keys, and OP says they added it just in case. Did I misunderstand something else?

Comment: I'd call out clearly in the answer that you can do that (probably quoting that part of the question) then. But it's a duplicate, so...